# RxJava2 - execute call synchronously

Tags: android, rx-java2

I've a `TestService`, where I do an async task to get my data. I would like to wait for the response before I continue.

```
public List<Data> getData() {
    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

    Disposable disposable = repository.getDataFromApi(false)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe( newData -> {
                data.addAll(newData);
            }, __ -> { });
    mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);

    //Here I want to stop till "Data" arraylist is filled with data 

    ... do something with data        
}
```

In Volley I could just call             `req.executeSynchronously();` to make it happen. As `getData()` have to return data already, I've to somehow make it wait till I get response. How to do it? I'm using `Single`.

My approach using getBlocking();

---

```
public List<Data> getData() {
    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

    Disposable disposable = repository.getDataFromApi(false)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .blockingGet();
            .subscribe( newData -> {
                data.addAll(newData);
            }, __ -> { });
    mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable);

    //Here I want to stop till "Data" arraylist is filled with data 

    ... do something with data        
}
```

It says `cannot resolve method subscribe`, so I'm probably calling it wrong..

```
fun getDataFromApi(): Single<List<Data>> {
    return service.getData()
            .map { jsonApiObject ->
                ...
                return@map data
            }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully you are aware that blocking is a strong antipattern in RxJava and you should avoid blocking whenever you can.

Saying that, if you really need to block, you have two options:

- use [`blockingGet()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#blockingGet--) which - as the name indicates - blocks current thread and directly returns value of publisher (`Single` in your case). This is probably what you were looking for. In your case:

  ```
  newData = repository.getDataFromApi(false).blockingGet();
  data.addAll(newData);
  ```
- synchronize with Java classes, like [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) - more complicated and I would use `blockingGet()` because it's more straightforward. But it's a possibility.

Comment: I updated post with your suggestions. Maybe you can help me correct my syntax of calling blockingGet(), as I can't wrap my head around it. I added extra information about my implementation.