# RxJava2 - no event received with .blockingFirst()

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to get a value from my Observable (BehaviorSubject.create())

When I run locationObservable.subscribe {} I receive the results withing a few seconds. However with

```
        try {
            it.locationObservable
                    .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .blockingFirst()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
        }
```

nothing happens with or without timeout. I simply receive "java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The source did not signal an event for 10 seconds and has been terminated". I have tried blockingFirst(), blockingLast() and blockingForEach(). Am I somehow blocking the thread that would provide me with the value?

EDIT: After moving it from the main thread it started working. Thank you everyone for your input.

Comment: Why are you trying to make a blocking call to begin with?  In general, you should avoid blocking with RxJava. Some more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52662255/4409409

Comment: blockingGet() referenced in the example you provided works with Single and I'm using BehaviorSubject. I'm aware that blocking may be defeating purpose of react programming but in my case I need to retrieve a snapshot of location from Android before I execute other parts of code and I don't want to have a listener every time I need a snapshot. I am aware of risks with blocking threads.

Answer (score 0):

The operator `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())` will queue all emitted items to be emitted in the IO thread of the Android application.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've just tried it with .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) and still, no event has been emitted.

Comment: try with these .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

Comment: That also doesn't work. I have tried using blockingSubscribe as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.just("fallback"))
```